# How do you get the frame.width of GameScene in a custom class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble trying to get the **frame.width** of GameScene into a custom class because I need the scene width for positioning nodes in my custom class init.

**HudController.swift snippet**

```
import SpriteKit

    class HudController:SKNode {
        var width:CGFloat

        override init(){
            width = GameScene().frame.width //I was hoping to add the scene width here
        }
    }
```

The following code crashes on me and I've tried heaps of other solutions with no success.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks!

**UPDATED CODE ===**

GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var hud = HudController(gameScene: self) 
    // set as global because I'm using it to also call hud functions in my game

}
```

HudController.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class HudController:SKNode {

    var width:CGFloat

    init(gameScene:SKScene){
        width = gameScene.size.width
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every node in SpriteKit can retrieve the scene where it lives using the `scene` property.

```
let node = SKNode()
node.scene
```

The `scene` property returns a `SKScene?`, the value is an **optional** because if the current node does not belong to a scene, of course there is not scene to retrieve.

Now, you could be tempted to use the `self.scene` property inside the initializer of your `HudController`.

```
class HudController: SKNode {
    var width:CGFloat

    override init() {
        super.init() //  error: property 'self.width' not initialized at super.init call
        width = self.scene!.frame.width
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

But it will now work because you cannot invoke `super.init` before having initialized the `width` property.

Fine, then you could try this.

```
class HudController: SKNode {
    var width:CGFloat

    override init() {
        width = self.scene!.frame.width // error: use of 'self' in property access 'scene' before super.init initializes self

        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Again compiler error because you are using `self` before having called `super.init()`.

And finally there is another problem, when the initializer is executed, the node it is being created has not a parent yet, so the `self.scene` property does return `nil`.

How to solve this?

### Solution

First of all declare you initializer to receive a `GameScene`.

```
class HudController: SKNode {
    var width: CGFloat

    init(gameScene:SKScene) {
        width = gameScene.frame.width
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now, when you create this object (I hope you are doing it from the scene or from a node already added to the scene otherwise we are in trouble) you simply write

```
class Foo : SKNode {

    func foo() {
        guard let scene = self.scene else { return }
        let controller = HudController(gameScene: scene)
    }
}
```

On the other hand if you are creating HudController from you scene you simply write:

```
class MyScene : SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        let controller = HudController(gameScene: self)
    }
}
```

That's it.

### Update

If you want an instance property of HudController inside your GameScene this is the code.

```
class HudController: SKNode {
    var width: CGFloat

    init(gameScene:SKScene) {
        width = gameScene.frame.width
        super.init() // <-- do not forget this
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var hud : HudController?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        hud = HudController(gameScene: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @appzYourLife, My **var hud = HudController(gameScene: self)** is a global var under class GameScene: SKScene { } not in the didMoveToView. I'm getting the following error: **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'HudController' with an argument list of type '(gameScene: NSObject -> () -> GameScene)'**. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added my new code to the question under **UPDATED CODE ===**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!